# not getting confirmation mail from onlyoffice community server

Tags: linux, email, onlyoffice

I installed the only office by using the below command :

docker run --net onlyoffice --name onlyoffice-document-server onlyoffice/documentserver

docker run --net onlyoffice --privileged -i -t -d --name onlyoffice-mail-server -p 25:25 -p 143:143 -p 587:587 -h 10.0.2.37 onlyoffice/mailserver

docker run --net onlyoffice -i -t -d --name onlyoffice-community-server -p 80:80 -p 5222:5222 -p 443:443 --link onlyoffice-mail-server:mail_server --link onlyoffice-document-server:document_server onlyoffice/communityserver

### and here are the logs of the mail server :

> [root@V37 ~]# docker logs 051df1fda9d6
>   [ INFO ] Checking configuration file: /usr/src/iRedMail/config ... [FOUND]
>   [ INFO ] Import installation process status from file: /usr/src/iRedMail/runtime/install.status.
>
> Start iRedMail Configurations
>   [ INFO ] Create required system accounts: vmail, iredapd.
>   [ INFO ] Configure Apache web server and PHP.
>   [ INFO ] Configure PHP.
>   [ INFO ] Configure MySQL database server.
>   [ INFO ] Configure Postfix (Message Transfer Agent).
>   [ INFO ] Configure Cluebringer (postfix policy server).
>   [ INFO ] Configure Dovecot (pop3/imap/managesieve server).
>   [ INFO ] Configure ClamAV (anti-virus toolkit).
>   [ INFO ] Configure Amavisd-new (interface between MTA and content checkers).
>   [ INFO ] Configure SpamAssassin (content-based spam filter).
>   [ INFO ] Configure OpenDkim.
>   [ INFO ] Configure Fail2ban (authentication failure monitor).
>   [ INFO ] Configure Server API.
>   [ INFO ] Configure SpamTrainer.
>   [ INFO ] Configure Awstats (logfile analyzer for mail and web server).
>   [ INFO ] Create self-signed SSL certification files (2048 bits).
>   [ INFO ] Generate a strong, unique Diffie Hellman Group with openssl, please > wait.
>
> iRedMail-0.9.2 installation and configuration complete.
>   [ INFO ] Disable SELinux in /etc/selinux/config.
>   [ INFO ] Removing package(s): sendmail
>   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
>   Setting up Remove Process
>   Resolving Dependencies
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package sendmail.x86_64 0:8.14.4-9.el6_8.1 will be erased
>   --> Processing Dependency: sendmail = 8.14.4-9.el6_8.1 for package: sendmail-> devel-8.14.4-9.el6_8.1.x86_64
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package sendmail-devel.x86_64 0:8.14.4-9.el6_8.1 will be erased
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Dependencies Resolved
>
> ===============================================================================
>   Package Arch Version Repository Size
>
> Removing:
>   sendmail x86_64 8.14.4-9.el6_8.1 @base 1.5 M
>   Removing for dependencies:
>   sendmail-devel x86_64 8.14.4-9.el6_8.1 @base 254 k
>
> Transaction Summary
>
> Remove 2 Package(s)
>
> Installed size: 1.8 M
>   Downloading Packages:
>   Running rpm_check_debug
>   Running Transaction Test
>   Transaction Test Succeeded
>   Running Transaction
>   Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
>   Erasing : sendmail-devel-8.14.4-9.el6_8.1.x86_64 1/2
>   Erasing : sendmail-8.14.4-9.el6_8.1.x86_64 2/2
>   Verifying : sendmail-devel-8.14.4-9.el6_8.1.x86_64 1/2
>   Verifying : sendmail-8.14.4-9.el6_8.1.x86_64 2/2
>
> Removed:
>   sendmail.x86_64 0:8.14.4-9.el6_8.1
>
> Dependency Removed:
>   sendmail-devel.x86_64 0:8.14.4-9.el6_8.1
>
> Complete!
>   grep: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: No such file or directory
>   [ INFO ] Copy firewall sample rules: /etc/sysconfig/iptables.
>   [ INFO ] Restarting firewall ...
>   [ INFO ] Copy MySQL sample file: /etc/my.cnf.
>   [ INFO ] Enable SSL support for MySQL server.
>
> URLs of installed web applications:
>   Webmail:
>   Username: postmaster@mailserver.onlyoffice.com, Password: orC61TNQ15
>   Web admin panel (iRedAdmin): 
>   You can login to above links with same credential:
>   o Username: postmaster@mailserver.onlyoffice.com
>   o Password: orC61TNQ15
>   Congratulations, mail server setup completed successfully. Please
>   read below file for more information:
>   /usr/src/iRedMail/iRedMail.tips
>   And it's sent to your mail account postmaster@mailserver.onlyoffice.com.
>   ********************* WARNING **************************************
>   *
>
> Rebooting your system is required to enable mail services.
>   mkdir: cannot create directory /var/log/httpd': File exists rm: cannot > remove/var/run/syslogd.pid': No such file or directory
>   rm: cannot remove /var/run/cbpolicyd.pid': No such file or directory rm: > cannot remove/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid': No such file or directory
>   Waiting for external MySql response
>   /usr/src/iRedMail/functions/mysql.sh: line 33: ECHO_INFO: command not found
>   /usr/src/iRedMail/functions/mysql.sh: line 36: ECHO_DEBUG: command not found
>   Starting crond: [ OK ]
>   Starting Dovecot Imap: [ OK ]
>   Starting system logger: [ OK ]
>   Starting amavisd: [ OK ]
>
> Starting postfix: [FAILED]
>   Starting cbpolicyd: [ OK ]
>   Starting Clam AntiVirus Daemon: LibClamAV Warning: > **************************************************
>   LibClamAV Warning: *** The virus database is older than 7 days!** 
>   LibClamAV Warning:  **Please update it as soon as possible. ***
>   LibClamAV Warning: **************************************************
>   [ OK ]
>   Starting clamd.amavisd: LibClamAV Warning: > **************************************************
>   LibClamAV Warning: *** The virus database is older than 7 days!** 
>   LibClamAV Warning:  **Please update it as soon as possible. ***
>   LibClamAV Warning: **************************************************
>   [ OK ]
>   Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully > qualified domain name, using 10.0.2.37 for ServerName
>   [ OK ]
>   Generating default DKIM keys: [ OK ]
>   Default DKIM keys for 0.2.37 created in /usr/local/etc/opendkim/keys.
>   Starting OpenDKIM Milter: [ OK ]
>   Starting spamd: [ OK ]
>   Starting fail2ban: [ OK ]
>   Starting server
>   [root@V37 ~]#

for more log information you can refer this link : 
https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/Docker-CommunityServer/issues/31

i have a VM with 2gb of RAM and 2gb of swap and 100 gb of storage,
since i am not geting the confirmation mail to my mail id, i am not able to access the fetures in the gui.
help in this....

Answer (score 0):

We do not recommend using --link for connecting the docker containers.
In our installation script we only use docker network

`docker network create --driver bridge onlyoffice`

I would strongly recommend to install ONLYOFFICE Community Edition using [the provided script](http://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/docker/enterprise/enterprise-script-installation.aspx).
Also note that the default smtp server responsible for the activation mails is notify.onlyoffice.info with sender email address postman@notify.onlyoffice.info